# how to fully change url without reloading the page to new url?

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, address-bar

I have gone through many questions asked here regarding changing url without reloading. Whilst I tried almost all of the methods, I am failed to fully change the url of a page including its domain name part without reloading the new page. How can I do that?

Comment: That is completely impossible.

Comment: Fortunately, that's not possible.

Comment: ooppss. nothing in this world could do this? what if we redirect the browser to the new url but as soon as it starts loading the page content and has changed the address bar, we stop it, save its address bar state and execute the new iframe or code?

Comment: @Roy: Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.  If that were possible, it would be the perfect phishing tool.

Comment: The two main reasons people want to do this are malicious (phishing) and thinking that they can make their site more secure by hiding addresses.  That won't work because the F12 developer tools in a browser can show people the real page address.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  What about the conceived procedure I just mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible for a good reason. You can get more info about this here: [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pushState to do what you describe. As an example (pulled from here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Change-URL-in-Browser-Address-Bar-without-reloading-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Page1" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page1', 'Page1.htm');" />
<input type="button" value="Page2" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page2', 'Page2.htm');" />
<input type="button" value="Page3" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page3', 'Page3.htm');" />
```

Note that this will *not* work if you are trying to open a test file directly in your browser (i.e., if the URL will be file://whatever). The browser behaves differently. You will need to serve it via some http server.

**Edit**
This doesn't answer the specific question asked by the OP. It will change the path, but you cannot change the hostname portion of a URL via pushState. As someone else already answered, it is not possible to change that without reloading the page due to the Same-origin policy. I left this here in case others just needed to change path portion of the URL.

Comment: But you can not do what OP is asking...change domain without being redirected

Comment: @rfestag I have already tried this and this code doesn't change the domain name of the url but merely the end part of the url.

Comment: Understood. As I stated previously, I missed the portion of your question regarding the hostname change. I have edited my answer to reflect that. What you want to do is not possible due to the Same-origin policy, as @marcogmonteiro stated above.